# Массив из GameObject-ов

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как изменить Scale всех объектов в массиве.
Я сделал так: 
    public GameObject[] scaler;

```
void  Update(){
if(landscape)...
```

А что дальше? Мне надо знать, как обратиться к этим GameObjects в массиве. В инспекторе естественно, их перетащу в массив. Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

обратится можно например вот так:

```
if(landscape)
{
    foreach (var obj in scaler)
    {
        obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2, 2, 2);
    }
}
```

**foreach** переберет итеративно каждый элемент массива

вместо *2 2 2* в присваивании конечно же нужно задать свои значения или переменные